# jQuery doesn't work, what to remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 different jQuerys, one is for slider and the other is for an animated menu.
I tried removing the jQuery one by one but it wouldn't work.
here's the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a.link').click(function () {  
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '400px', '800px', '1200px' , '1600px')
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '800px', '1600px', '2400px' , '3200px')
        //add this
        $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        //end add this
        return false;  
    });  
});

function setPosition(check, div, p1, p2, p3) 
{
    if(check==='#box1')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p1, 800);
        }
    else if(check==='#box2')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p2, 800);
        }
    else if(check==='#box3')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p3, 800);
        }
};
</script>
```

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
            animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-5', classout : 'dl-animate-out-5' }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried searching for answers, removing one of the jQuery would not work.
I don't really know how to manipulate these codes because I have a little knowledge with jQuery. 
Could anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: What do you meant removing the jquery? It is the library so if you don't want to use it just remove the script embeded.

Comment: I mean should I remove some code or add some? I  have this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>   and  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   HOW to make it both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot combine 2 jquery in one page.. because the code will confius which jquery need to call is it `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` or `jquery.min.js` . The solution either you remove one of them or use the latest one and put it above all the code so it can be called.

Comment: Oh! okay thanks lifesaver. I didnt know that I should put it above the other codes. Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: hahaha.. please rate my answer.. :P ..

Comment: This is not always the correct answer because a library might require a specific version of jQuery to work.

Comment: it the best solution to get simple code if both code depends on same jquery.. if you really need to put 2 jquery without conflict you can use jQuery.noConflict() but more code needed.. [link]http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the difference jquery version in the same page, so it's conflict. Let try use one of them and keep using the later version.

Comment: Always welcome! please vote my answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not running because it's a conflict.

In this case, the first thing you do is that you head over to the jQuery API documentation and read about [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

This is one of the good examples coming from the documentation:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.noConflict demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! however, i solved it not by using no.conflict but just replacing the whole script 1.3.2.min.js with 1.9.1... Thanks again anyway :)

Comment: @user3044124 I gave you this solution incase both the scripts are needed. Sometimes these libraries have specific dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

the jquery-scrollto-1.4 is not the version 1.4 of jquery,it means the version of this plugins

Comment: Okay, but do you know how I could solve this? So that both slider and menu would work? THanks

Comment: Oh wait I left another code. I also have this one,  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>